# Sync data set from Desktop PC to several Android Tablets

Tags: android, synchronization

I want to be able to sync a "master" data set from a desktop machine to several tablets.  I cannot guarentee all devices will be available at the point the data changes so I need the tablets to update when the data set is updated.

The data set sits in a folder on the desktop, its just a bunch of PDF files and a few txt files, nothing special.

At one end of the scale I guess I could run a script that just copies the folder over to the tablet, data updated or not via USB mount.  Not really the way I want to go, I want something a bit more slick.

I guess i could call ADB from within a desktop JAVA app to push the files across, although this seems like it might be difficult if several devices want to update their local data set at one time.

Finally, I was wondering about something like OpenMobster (https://code.google.com/p/openmobster/) but I am new to this and it seems fairly complicated, is it worth the complication?

Are there any other options I am missing?  I plan on using a Linux based Sync PC if that makes any difference at all?  The final restriction I want to cover is that none of this can be connected to the Internet so Dropbox etc are non starters.  They were my first thought but sadly no go.

Thanks for the help, I know this is fairly general, but I need a push in the right direction to start more research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the job:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pcfilesync&hl=en

Maybe this question is better located at superuser.com?

Comment: thanks, I had hoped to code this myself but then there are options on the play store.